# How to delete a group post with facebook php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook, post, sdk

How do I use the php-sdk to delete a group post in facebook? The following code works with a post on my feed (if I pass in post id) and on my page (if I pass in pageid_postid).  However, I can't find the right combination to delete my post from a group. I've tried postid and groupid_postid. Nothing is working. Help, please!!

```
<?php
require '../facebook/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '00000000000',
    'secret' => '000000000000000000',
));

$postid = $_GET['postid'];
$facebook->api("/".$postid,"DELETE");

header("Location: index.php");
die();
```

Just an FYI, this is not production code. It's simply functional code.

Answer (score 0):

OMG what a tool. So, I had manage_groups permission when I needed user_groups permission. That just cost me an hour and a half.